# Border-top from tbody and border-bottom from thead don't work at the same time?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have  a very basic table:

```
<table id="ttable5" class="table-default">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
                <th class="sort-date">Provincia</th>
            <th class="sort-digit">Municipio</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td class="tablaprim">1VESTIBULUM TORTOR NISL </td>
            <td>Sevilla</td>
            <td>Castilleja de la Cuesta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td class="tablaprim">4VESTIBULUM TORTOR NISL </td>
            <td>Sevilla</td>
            <td>Castilleja de la Cuesta</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to have this:

```
------------
head
------------1px border #fff
------------3px border #gray
body
------------
```

I can only get to show one of the borders, never two at the same time. It's not really important but I'm curious about what is causing this issue.

My css:

```
thead{border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
tbody{border-top: 3px solid #4d4d4d;}
```

EDIT:

Since it seems like the border-collapse might be the issue but I can't make it work I've set up this sandbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/bRVEu/

There you can see there's only a grey border, there should be a 1px white border right on top of it

Comment: Your background isn't white is it ? :)

Comment: no, my background is green on the head and a lighter grey on the body :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to

a) use both `border-collapse` and `border-spacing`

b) set the borders on the most **interior** elements of the `table`

c) you must set `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` on the `table` so it inherits

so

```
table {
  background: pink; 
  border: 0; 
  border-collapse: separate; 
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
}

thead tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red; 
  border-collapse: separate; 
  border-spacing: 5px 5px;
} 

tbody tr#first td {
  border-top: 3px solid #4d4d4d; 
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px 5px;
}
```

I changed some of the colors to make it easier to see.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Pf7My/1/

Comment: `border-spacing` can be applied only to the whole table, not elements.

Comment: Complementing: on the fiddle you also had to put the borders on `th` and `td` elements, instead of `thead` and `tbody`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `border-collapse`. If it's `collapse`, then the browser will merge adjacent borders.

Comment: It actually was but removing that didn't change the way my thead and tbody behave :S In fact without it the borders I mentioned in my question don't show (neither of them)

Comment: Try to use a padding or margin on one of them to simulate a border.

Comment: I had already tried that but it doesn't work (no padding or margin are applied). I edited my post with a link to a sandbox, maybe you can see it there.

Answer (score 0):

The borders are probable 'merged' by border-collapse. Try setting `border-collapse: seperate;` on both the tbody and thead

Comment: I tried ths but still only one border will prevail (the bigger one)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `border-collapse: separate;` on both the `tbody` and `thead`. Not "seperate"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if we put it in the cell element :)

```
.table-default {
    border-collapse: separate; //DON'T FORGET TO MAKE IT SEPARATE
    border-spacing: 0;
}    
.table-default th { 
    border-bottom: gray solid 3px; 
}
.table-default td { 
    border-top: white solid 1px; 
}
```